# Why iterating on a collection does not require index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

I'm trying to sort my confusions learning python.

```
>>> cities = ['London', "Toronto", 'Paris', 'Oslo']
>>> cities
['London', 'Toronto', 'Paris', 'Oslo']
>>> for i in cities:
...     print(i)
...
```

London
Toronto
Paris
Oslo

```
>>> for i in cities:
...     print(cities[i])
...
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
>>> cities[0]
'London'
```

In the loop, it refuses the index, but outside of the loop, it seems to accept. Confused!!!

Comment: Why do you think `i` is an index? It isn't. It is an item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you normally loop over the list, the iterated item is the element of it.
When you want to get index, then you need to use `enumerate` function.

```
for index, item in enumerate(cities):
    # here the `index` is the index, item is the element
    print(cities[index])
    print(item)
    ...
```